# Which is better for creating json request body: method with lots of arguments or builder pattern?

Tags: java, json, design-patterns

In my tests I send requests with such a body:

```
{
  "param": "value",
  "param": "value",
  "param": "value",
  "param": "value",
  "param": {
    "param": value,
    "param": "value"
  },
  "param": "value"
}
```

For each test I use different combination of values (params are always the same). So my question is which is better to use: a method with a bunch of arguments like

```
public JSONObject createRequestBody(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7) {...}
```

or a builder pattern? 
Or maybe there is another solution.
Thanks!

Comment: Use a pojo with all those params as its fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, builder patterns are much more flexible. If you use constructors directly, it's harder to change the signature (when you add or remove new parameters). With the builder pattern, you just call a new method.

Answer (score 0):

why not construct a dict? then pass the dict to function createRequestBody, in this function, you can encode the dict to json object.

Comment: sorry, what does 'dict' mean?

Comment: a dict includes all your parameters, like your json data